# Plot spectrogram of overnight sleep EEG using MNE

Tags: spectrogram, time-frequency, mne-python, eeglab

Is it possible to plot the spectrogram of overnight sleep EEG data in mne? I don't want to create epochs but, have the spectrogram of continuous 8-9 hours. The examples I see in e.g. EEGlab (Matlab) have perfect color distinction which makes the outcome very readable. I would be grateful if you help me produce something similar but in mne.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible and quite easy!

Raphael Vallat's package [`yasa`](https://raphaelvallat.com/yasa) has a function for doing exactly this for a single EEG channel from long-duration sleep data:
https://raphaelvallat.com/yasa/build/html/generated/yasa.plot_spectrogram.html

The function uses multitapers for estimating Wigner spectra, implemented in the package [`lspopt`](https://github.com/hbldh/lspopt), and is quite fast. While you could use this directly, `yasa` takes care of a lot of moving parts and provides a more convenient interface.

The function accepts a 1D NumPy array, so you'll need to get the data for a single channel from the `mne.Raw` object. For instance, if your EEG data is stored in the variable `raw`, you can extract the data as a 2D NumPy array using `raw.get_data()` and then select the desired row (channel). There are plenty of ways of selecting data, tabulated nicely in the documentation:
https://mne.tools/dev/auto_tutorials/raw/10_raw_overview.html#summary-of-ways-to-extract-data-from-raw-objects